How can I find Mean[data] Median[data] Quartiles[data] Variance[data] StandardDeviation[data] of a grouped frequency table
I have a data
Clear["Global`*"];
data = {134, 121, 147, 158, 178, 127, 141, 175, 123, 145, 147, 132, 
   161, 172, 156, 123, 163, 126, 127, 163, 155, 148, 177, 142, 168, 
   179, 136, 164, 174, 156, 137, 130, 140, 145, 160, 169, 136, 130, 
   128, 148, 157, 121, 153, 156, 120, 127, 133, 169, 133, 130};

I tried
Mean[data]
Median[data]
Quartiles[data]
Variance[data]
StandardDeviation[data]

and got

If I have a table

I tried
ClearAll["Global`*"]
data = {{120, 130}, {130, 140}, {140, 150}, {150, 160}, {160, 
    170}, {170, 180}};
freq = {10, 10, 9, 7, 8, 6};
list = Table[Mean[data[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[data]}];
n = Sum[freq[[i]], {i, 1, Length[data]}]
mymean = freq . list/n
myVariance = 
 Sum[freq[[i]]*(list[[i]] - mymean)^2, {i, 1, Length[data]}]/n
myStandardDeviation = Sqrt[myVariance]


How can I find  Median, Quartiles of above grouped frequency table?

Through[{Mean, Median, Quartiles, Variance, StandardDeviation}[data]] is a nice way to map several functions across one dataset

There are probably several alternatives depending on exactly what kind of statistics you want, your context, and what data you actually have. If you literally just have that table (i.e. if we ignore the data you provided, which seems to be the basis of that table), then I might try WeightedData and/or HistogramDistribution.
boundaries = Range[120, 180, 10];
frequencies = {10, 10, 9, 7, 8, 6};
binMeans = Mean /@ Partition[boundaries, 2, 1];
weighted = WeightedData[binMeans, frequencies];
weightedHist = HistogramDistribution[weighted, {10}];

{Mean[weightedHist], Mean[weighted]}
(* {736/5, 736/5} *)

{Variance[weightedHist], Variance[weighted]}
(* {289.493, 339.565} *)

{StandardDeviation[weightedHist], StandardDeviation[weighted]}
(* {17.0145, 18.4273} *)

... and so forth
Based on your updates, I thought I should point out that Mathematica uses unbiased variance, while your "by hand" computations use biased variance. So, again, it depends on which statistics exactly that you want and how you want to model the data represented by your table.
